# Кнопка, которая будет появляться только на смартфонах

Tags: button

Как сделать кнопку на сайте, которая будет появляться только на маленьких экранах (смартфонах)? А в полно экранном режиме ее не должно быть

Comment: Вопрос сводится к вопросу, как определить что сайт на смартфоне. Показ кнопки - мелочь. Про "в полно экранном режиме" - не понятно к чему это.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
min-width: 768px
```

размер экрана с которого не будет видна кнопка

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .small-btn {
    display: none;
  }
    
}
```

```html
<button class="small-btn">Click ME</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все получилось

Comment: рад помочь, тогда закрывайте вопрос ))